# Fuelphp ORM can't access related table

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I have two tables (team, team_managers) that I am trying to access with ORM. I am getting the error "Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Notice ]: Trying to get property of non-object".

This is the code that is throwing the error:

```
<?php
$team = Model_Team::find('all', array('related' => array('team_managers')));
$team_managers = $team->team_managers;

foreach($team_managers as $tm){
    echo $tm->id;
}
```

Doing this works, but I think it defeats the purpose of ORM:

```
<?php
$team = Model_Team::find('all', array('related' => array('team_managers')));
$team_managers = Model_Team_Manager::find('all');

foreach($team_managers as $tm){
    echo $tm->id;
}
```

In the team model, I have this relationship:

```
protected static $_has_many = array('team_managers' => array(
'model_to' => 'Model_Team_Manager',
'key_from' => 'id',
'key_to' => 'team_id',
));
```

How can I get it to work with $team->team_managers  ?

Comment: It actually does work if I call a specific team instead of "all". Does anyone know why I can't call it with "all"? In fuelphp documentation they use "all" and it works. =[ http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/relations/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are doing is OK, what I don't understand is why you are trying to access `$team->team_managers`

`$team` in an array of `Model_Team` objects, this is your error.

Try the following :

```
$teams = Model_Team::find('all', array('related' => array('team_managers')));

foreach ($teams as $team) {
    foreach ($team->team_managers as $team_manager) {
        echo $team_manager->id;
    }
}
```